# How to reset numeration if there are gaps between numbers and they are in random order?

Tags: plsql

I have products displayed in two HTML tables. Their order is numbered from 1 to infinity, and is continuous through both tables. For example, if the number of the last product in the first table is 5, then the number of the first product in second table will be 6, etc.

When product from the second table is moved to the first table, I need to manually change order numbers in the database. So, if product 8 is moved to the first table, it is now product number 6 there (the last product). This I've done. Now the first table has numeration ...4 - 5 - 6, and the second table: 6 - 7 - 9 - 10 - etc., but needs to be set to 7 - 8 - 9 - 10, etc.

Information about numeration of both tables is stored in one database table. (Each product has a parameter indicating if it goes into table 1 or 2, but to get to it I need to do an inner join.)

What is a good way how to reset the second table numeration with PL/SQL?

I have something along the lines of

```
select order_number
into v_old_order_number
from products
where product_id = moved_product_id; --find product's current order number

select product_id bulk collect into v_first_table_product_ids
from products p 
inner join table_with_parameter t
on p.product_id = t.product_id
and t.parameter = 1; --find all first table product ids

select max(order_number) + 1
into v_new_order_number
from products
where product_id member of v_first_table_product_ids; --find max order value of first table
                                                      --products, put in variable and add 1

update products
set order_number = v_new_order_number
where product_id = moved_product_id; --change our product's order number to new order number

update products
set order_number = order_number + 1
where order_number => v_new_order_number
and order_number <= v_oold_order_number
and product_id != moved_product_id; --change all numbers greater than new_order_no 
                                    --(except if it has the moved product's id) 
                                    --and smaller than old_order_no.
```

I'm sure this can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future please include a small example (like the one I built below) that people can use to assist you.  This helps clarify your question and makes sure the time people are volunteering on SO is well spent.

I think you can do what you want with a MERGE.  I am using dense_rank() to calculate the order based on the table ID and the existing order and re-numbering every product.  The MERGE will then only update the rows that need to be changed.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    table_id NUMBER, 
    product_id NUMBER,
    order_id NUMBER);
  
ALTER TABLE products  
ADD CONSTRAINT products_pk
PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
USING INDEX;

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 1, 1);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 2, 2);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 3, 3);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 4, 4);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 5, 5);

  INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 6, 6);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 7, 7);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 8, 8);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 9, 9);
  INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 10, 10);

  COMMIT;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM products
 ORDER BY table_id,
          order_id;
/*
T P O
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 3
1 4 4
1 5 5
2 6 6
2 7 7
2 8 8
2 9 9
2 10  10
*/

UPDATE products 
   SET table_id = 1
 WHERE product_id = 8;
 
SELECT *
  FROM products
 ORDER BY table_id,
          order_id;
/*
T P O
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 3
1 4 4
1 5 5 <--
1 8 8 <--
2 6 6
2 7 7 <--
2 9 9 <--
2 10  10
*/

MERGE INTO products p
USING (SELECT product_id,
              dense_rank() over(ORDER BY table_id, order_id) AS order_id
         FROM products) x
ON (p.product_id = x.product_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
     SET p.order_id = x.order_id
   WHERE p.order_id != x.order_id;
-- 4 rows updated

SELECT *
  FROM products
 ORDER BY table_id,
          order_id;
/*
T P O
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 3
1 4 4
1 5 5
1 8 6
2 6 7
2 7 8
2 9 9
2 10  10
*/
```